# invoking an ant command via make

Tags: java, xml, ant, makefile

I'm trying to do soemthing which may not be done that often. It's part of our test code which uses a wide variety tools: java, ant, make, and xml.

Our java testing tool parses XML. It gets an argument via an XML tag from a file:

```
<TAG>-Darg1="argument1" -Darg2="argument2"</TAG>
```

Within the java code, I'm calling the make command. The make command is invoked from java (via ProcessBuilder).

In the makefile, I am calling ant where the `-Darg="argument1" -Darg2="argument2"` args should be passed.

But it's not working.

Anyways, it seems that the `-D` from the `-Darg1= ...` part is not compatible with make, so I'm trying to enclose that in a variable that I can pass through make to ant. Within ant it's taking the variable "`RULES_ARG`" and treating that as one argument, instead of two.

I've tried various quoting mechanisms in xml: "-Darg1=argument1 -Darg2=argument2", "-Darg1="argument1" -Darg2="argument2""

and also where it's invoked in java: `"RULES_ARGS="+RulesArgs+" ",  "RULES_ARGS=\""+RulesArgs+"\" "` (in combination with the xml part).

etc. all with no desirable result.

I was wondering if anyone has tried to do something similar, and the working approach to the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no way to answer this with the information given.  Please provide the make rule you're using to invoke ant, an example of how you're invoking make, the output you expect to see, and the output you actually get.  Be sure to remove any `@` prefixes on your recipe lines so you can see exactly what commands make is running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you're trying to run make with `-D` options?  That won't work because make doesn't support `-D`.

If you're trying to pass some flags through the make command line to be used on the ant invocation, then you should do something like this: when you run make set a variable on the make command line:

```
make ANTFLAGS='-DFOO -DBAR -DBAZ'
```

Then inside your makefile, when you run ant, pass that variable:

```
runant:
         ant $(ANTFLAGS) ...
```

If that's not what you're trying to do please clarify your question.  For example, you say *it's not working* and *no desirable result*, but you don't give any details about what errors or incorrect behavior you see.  Such error messages would go a long way towards clarifying exactly what's going on.

Comment: I was trying not to clutter the original post with too much details, especially since I was trying different options which also didn't seem to work.

Comment: Oops, hit the return key too soon. Anyways, it seems that ant requires arguments to be passed as properties. Passing the properties like you do above would actually look like: ant -Darg1="argument1" -Darg2="argument2" if on the command line. However, it's not on the command line, it's being passed via make which is being passed via java....anyways, I found a partial solution by passing in just one argument, a properties file, and then passing however many arguments I want via the properties file. Not the solution I was looking for, but one that works for now.

Comment: By leaving out some info (as you stated above), I was hoping this would ring a bell with someone that overcame this issue. I'm still hoping for that...

Comment: Unfortunately, single-quotes did't work, but maybe not because it "didn't work". Our command line parser is kinda brain dead, but we pass command line args thru it so that we can pass that along to sigar. We use the command line parser both for creating a PTQL query, and also invoking ProcessBuilder. We keep arguments together if they are enclosed in double quotes, but not single quotes.